# Adding up values read from text file - C programming

Tags: c

I'm still new to C. I need to find the total transaction for combo and ala-carte. Hence, I created a function to read through each line and then add up to get the total combo meal and total ala-carte transactions inside my while loop. However, I'm not getting any values printed out at all.

output from daily_transactions function:

```
   Total combo meal transaction : 0
   Total ala-carte transaction : 0
   Total sales : RM 0.00
```

I coded it using fscanf()

```
    tfptr = fopen("trans.txt", "r");
    //loops until end of file to read last line
    while( fgets(str, sizeof(str), tfptr)!=NULL ){ //fgets() will return NULL when the file is over                                                                                                     
        fscanf(tfptr, "%u:%u:%f\n", &combo_trans, &ala_trans, &total);
        c_trans += combo_trans;
        a_trans += ala_trans;
        grand_total += total;
    }                                           
    daily_transactions(c_trans, a_trans, grand_total);                                                                                  
    fclose(tfptr);
```

text file:

```
0:1:7.98
1:1:20.97
2:1:35.96
2:2:44.95
2:2:44.95
3:2:55.94
```

edit: the function to print out the transactions

```
void daily_transactions(int combo_trans, int ala_trans, float grand_total){
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    printf("   Daily Transactions\n");
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    printf("Total combo meal transaction : %d\n", combo_trans);
    printf("Total ala-carte transaction : %d\n", ala_trans);
    printf("Total sales : RM %.2f\n", grand_total);                     
    puts("------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: where are you printing them.? not in the above code that's for sure

Comment: Use `sscanf` instead of `fscanf` ?

Comment: I used `sscanf` however, it only reads in the last line's values, which is not what I wanted. I want to add all up.

Comment: It seems that the presented code is different from the actual code or is making a mistake in the part not presented.

Comment: See [DEMO](https://ideone.com/85IkM0)

Comment: Check that whichever of `fscanf()` or `sscanf()` you use returns the correct value (3).  You have problems if it returns anything else.  Otherwise, you need to show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've shown fails on the 'complete' category; it is too minimal, therefore.  You don't show the variables being initialized, for example (if they're not explicitly zeroed, you could have problems).

Comment: I got the answer I needed, thanks. Sample answer can be found in BLUEPIXXY's DEMO. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of solving this problem, but here is my code. I am not sure if it works, because I have not tested it yet. But hopefully it gives you an idea on how to solve the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{ 
  FILE *infile;

  infile=fopen("filein","r");

  int num_trans=0;
  int j=0;
  int combomeal[20],alameal[20];
  totalsales[20]={0};
  totalcombo[20]={0};
  totalala[20]={0};


 while(fscanf(infile,"%d %d",&combomeal[num_trans],&alameal[num_trans]) !=EOF) num_trans++;


 printf(" Total Combo Meal    Total Ala Meal      Total Sales\n");

  for(j=0;j<num_trans;j++)
   {
     totalcombo[j]+=combomeal[j];
     totalala[j]+=totalala[j];
     totalsales[j]=combomeal[j]+totalala[j];
     printf("  %d                    %d                     %d\n",totalcombo[j],totalala[j],totalsales[j]);      
   }


 fclose(infile); 

}
```